# Stanford NLP: Tokenize output on a single line?

Tags: stanford-nlp

Can we have a tokenizer output on a single line like that of Apache OpenNLP with the command line tool?
http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tokenizer.shtml
https://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/1.5.3/manual/opennlp.html#tools.tokenizer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DocumentPreprocessor`](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/process/DocumentPreprocessor.html), either programmatically or from the command line.

From the CLI:

```
$ echo "This is a test. And some more." | java edu.stanford.nlp.process.DocumentPreprocessor 2>/dev/null
This is a test .
And some more .
```

You can do the same thing programmatically; see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9493264/176075).

Comment: Thx Jon! I notice the output is tokenized, and I would like to avoid that. Any way to skip tokenization with Stanford NLP?

Comment: Yes—use whitespace tokenization. Run `DocumentPreprocessor` with the `-help` option for details.