# Parsing textfile with citations

Tags: php, regex, parsing, nlp

The issue is that I’m trying to segment the text file by sentences using php. I currently using the following function:

```
$results = preg_split('/(?<=[.?!])\s+/', $stringtest, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

The issue is that with sentences like these:

```
In his book The Symposium, Plato wrote “Those who are halves of a man whole pursue males, and being slices, so to speak, of the male, love men throughout their boyhood, and take pleasure in physical contact with men” (qtd. in Isay 11).
```

It splits it like this:

```
[0] In his book The Symposium, Plato wrote “Those who are halves of a man whole pursue males, and being slices, so to speak, of the male, love men throughout their boyhood, and take pleasure in physical contact with men” (qtd. 
[1] in Isay 11).
```

Another example is:

```
Dr. Evelyn Hooker, a heterosexual psychologist...
```

**The Dr. part would be an issue.**

These texts are all from the MASC corpus for NLP.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @JayBlanchard: I guess OP wishes to split on punctuation. But since they are also present elsewhere it's causing trouble.

Comment: I don't think regex is a very good tool for this.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew One of the issues is that the answer to the duplicate question does not account for instances such as: Dobbens reasoned that most parents would not raise their children to be homosexual; “They’re not like ‘My child’s going to be gay!”’ (Dobbens). It splits it into ".....gay!'" and (Dobbens). And I can't ask follow up questions there because I don't have enough points.

Comment: [It does not split the sentence at all.](http://ideone.com/hhasAk) What do you expect? I just added `qtd` to the list of abbrevs - http://ideone.com/cIBdr0 - and all works well.

Comment: You should explain what you expect for each case in the question itself.

Comment: Sorry, the problem only arises when there is another sentence after the "(Dobbens)." example: http://ideone.com/qJ1BfC Its the third example. The second element in the array should be part of the first ( i.e. the citations Dobbens should be part of the first sentence)

Comment: But what is the rule? How can you define it verbally? Any `(` followed after a closing citation symbol (or even after a straight double quote) should be part of the preceding sentence?

Comment: The citation should be part of the sentence where it is used ( the sentence immediately before the citation). This is particularly important when the sentence before the citation ( the citation being (Dobbens). ) is a quote with punctuation ( in this case '!' )

Comment: Ok, so the rule is: a final punctuation (`[.!?]`) followed with `”` or `’` (or maybe we need to also add `'` and `"`/`»`) and then having `(` should not be split, right? See [this demo](http://ideone.com/QSgPxs).

Comment: See http://ideone.com/QSgPxs

Comment: The issue is that in scenarios like "!”’(Dobbens)." it works because there is no space between the " and the (. But when you put a space it breaks. Is there a way for us to add a regex  to fix this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142546/discussion-between-39fredy-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Comment: As for the latest regex remark, I tried almost the same code and [got expected results in both cases, with and without spaces](http://ideone.com/wO0Fra)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may extend [@ndn's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35109078/3832970) to achieve what you need. Note that `$before_regexes` contain a list of known abbreviations, add those that are present in your corpora. I added `qtd`  there.

Then, note that `$before_regexes` and `$after_regexes` are paired. I added `'/(?:[”’"\'»])\s*\Z/u'` / `'/\A(?:\(\p{L})/u'` pair and marked it as a non-sentence boundary (with the first `false`  in the `$is_sentence_boundary` array. The regex pair means: find a quotation mark (`”’"'»`), 0+ whitespaces, and then followed with `(` (with `\(`) and any Unicode letter (`\p{L}`), then there should be no split.

```
function sentence_split($text) {
    $before_regexes = array('/(?:[”’"\'»])\s*\Z/u',
        '/(?:(?:[\'\"„][\.!?…][\'\"”]\s)|(?:[^\.]\s[A-Z]\.\s)|(?:\b(?:St|Gen|Hon|Prof|Dr|Mr|Ms|Mrs|[JS]r|Col|Maj|Brig|Sgt|Capt|Cmnd|Sen|Rev|Rep|Revd)\.\s)|(?:\b(?:St|Gen|Hon|Prof|Dr|Mr|Ms|Mrs|[JS]r|Col|Maj|Brig|Sgt|Capt|Cmnd|Sen|Rev|Rep|Revd)\.\s[A-Z]\.\s)|(?:\bApr\.\s)|(?:\bAug\.\s)|(?:\bBros\.\s)|(?:\bCo\.\s)|(?:\bCorp\.\s)|(?:\bDec\.\s)|(?:\bDist\.\s)|(?:\bFeb\.\s)|(?:\bInc\.\s)|(?:\bJan\.\s)|(?:\bJul\.\s)|(?:\bJun\.\s)|(?:\bMar\.\s)|(?:\bNov\.\s)|(?:\bOct\.\s)|(?:\bPh\.?D\.\s)|(?:\bSept?\.\s)|(?:\b\p{Lu}\.\p{Lu}\.\s)|(?:\b\p{Lu}\.\s\p{Lu}\.\s)|(?:\bcf\.\s)|(?:\be\.g\.\s)|(?:\besp\.\s)|(?:\bet\b\s\bal\.\s)|(?:\bvs\.\s)|(?:\p{Ps}[!?]+\p{Pe} ))\Z/su',
        '/(?:(?:[\.\s]\p{L}{1,2}\.\s))\Z/su',
        '/(?:(?:[\[\(]*\.\.\.[\]\)]* ))\Z/su',
        '/(?:(?:\b(?:pp|[Vv]iz|i\.?\s*e|[Vvol]|[Rr]col|maj|Lt|[Ff]ig|[Ff]igs|[Vv]iz|[Vv]ols|[Aa]pprox|[Ii]ncl|Pres|[Dd]ept|min|max|[Gg]ovt|lb|ft|c\.?\s*f|vs|qtd)\.\s))\Z/su',
        '/(?:(?:\b[Ee]tc\.\s))\Z/su',
        '/(?:(?:[\.!?…]+\p{Pe} )|(?:[\[\(]*…[\]\)]* ))\Z/su',
        '/(?:(?:\b\p{L}\.))\Z/su',
        '/(?:(?:\b\p{L}\.\s))\Z/su',
        '/(?:(?:\b[Ff]igs?\.\s)|(?:\b[nN]o\.\s))\Z/su',
        '/(?:(?:[\"”\']\s*))\Z/su',
        '/(?:(?:[\.!?…][\x{00BB}\x{2019}\x{201D}\x{203A}\"\'\p{Pe}\x{0002}]*\s)|(?:\r?\n))\Z/su',
        '/(?:(?:[\.!?…][\'\"\x{00BB}\x{2019}\x{201D}\x{203A}\p{Pe}\x{0002}]*))\Z/su',
        '/(?:(?:\s\p{L}[\.!?…]\s))\Z/su');
    $after_regexes = array('/\A(?:\(\p{L})/u',
        '/\A(?:)/su',
        '/\A(?:[\p{N}\p{Ll}])/su',
        '/\A(?:[^\p{Lu}])/su',
        '/\A(?:[^\p{Lu}]|I)/su',
        '/\A(?:[^p{Lu}])/su',
        '/\A(?:\p{Ll})/su',
        '/\A(?:\p{L}\.)/su',
        '/\A(?:\p{L}\.\s)/su',
        '/\A(?:\p{N})/su',
        '/\A(?:\s*\p{Ll})/su',
        '/\A(?:)/su',
        '/\A(?:\p{Lu}[^\p{Lu}])/su',
        '/\A(?:\p{Lu}\p{Ll})/su');
    $is_sentence_boundary = array(false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, true, true);
    $count = 13;

    $sentences = array();
    $sentence = '';
    $before = '';
    $after = substr($text, 0, 10);
    $text = substr($text, 10);

    while($text != '') {
        for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
            if(preg_match($before_regexes[$i], $before) && preg_match($after_regexes[$i], $after)) {
                if($is_sentence_boundary[$i]) {
                    array_push($sentences, $sentence);
                    $sentence = '';
                }
                break;
            }
        }

        $first_from_text = $text[0];
        $text = substr($text, 1);
        $first_from_after = $after[0];
        $after = substr($after, 1);
        $before .= $first_from_after;
        $sentence .= $first_from_after;
        $after .= $first_from_text;
    }

    if($sentence != '' && $after != '') {
        array_push($sentences, $sentence.$after);
    }

    return $sentences;
}
```

See the [PHP demo](http://ideone.com/wO0Fra).