# Finding start and end point of sentence in a paragraph StanfordCoreNLP

Tags: java, indexing, split, stanford-nlp, sentence

I was wondering how I can find the start and end position of a sentence in a paragraph using StanfordCoreNLP. Right now I am using DocumentPreprocessor to split the paragraph into sentences. Is it possible to get the start and end index of where the sentence is actually located in the original text?

I am using the code from another question asked on here.

```
String paragraph = "My 1st sentence. “Does it work for questions?” My third sentence.";
Reader reader = new StringReader(paragraph);
DocumentPreprocessor dp = new DocumentPreprocessor(reader);
List<String> sentenceList = new ArrayList<String>();

for (List<HasWord> sentence : dp) {
   String sentenceString = Sentence.listToString(sentence);
   sentenceList.add(sentenceString.toString());
}

for (String sentence : sentenceList) {
   System.out.println(sentence);
}
```

Taken from: [How can I split a text into sentences using the Stanford parser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9492707/how-can-i-split-a-text-into-sentences-using-the-stanford-parser)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick and dirty way to do this would be:

```
import edu.stanford.nlp.simple.*;

Document doc = new Document("My 1st sentence. “Does it work for questions?” My third sentence.");
for (Sentence sentence : doc.sentences()) {
  System.out.println(sentence.characterOffsetBegin(0) + " -- " + sentence.characterOffsetEnd(sentence.length() - 1));
}
```

Otherwise, you can extract the `CharacterOffsetBeginAnnotation` and `CharacterOffsetEndAnnotation` from a CoreLabel, and use that to find the token's offset in the original text.

Answer (score 0):

See https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreLabel for examples of getting CharacterOffsetEndAnnotation

Comment: Link answers are okay, but generally you need give a description of what the link says. This is because the website you linked may go down, meaning your answer will be useless.