# Stanford NLP Java Method Translation Issue

Tags: java, c#, stanford-nlp, translate

I'm using the Stanford NLP tools in C#, via the IKVM Java interface.  Also getting ideas from https://sergey-tihon.github.io/Stanford.NLP.NET/StanfordCoreNLP.html

```
String text = "This is a test sentence.";
var props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, parse");
var curDir = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(modelsDirectory);
var pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(curDir);
var annotation = new Annotation(text);
pipeline.annotate(annotation);
```

This code works fine to get my `Annotation`.  However, when I try to access the annotation to extract various entities in the annotation, I run into trouble. Using code from this: [How can I split a text into sentences using the Stanford parser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9492707/how-can-i-split-a-text-into-sentences-using-the-stanford-parser)

```
List<CoreMap> sentences = annotation.get(SentencesAnnotation.class);
```

Not clear how to translate `SentencesAnnotation.class` into something that C# will accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, Java Foo.class translates to C# typeof(Foo), so C# should accept the following:

```
IList<CoreMap> sentences = annotation.get(typeof(SentencesAnnotation));
```

Comment: I could only get the code to compile and `sentences` to populate by using the `var` type.